# How to solve String must be exactly one character long? C# .net error

Tags: c#, .net, string, char, inputbox

I am trying to get input from user by using `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll`. Then convert the input from [***string***] to [***char***] type. But it gives me this error when I run the code:

```
*An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
String must be exactly one character long.*
```

Sample code:

```
      string directions = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("1 = Buy, 2 = Sell", "Select side", "Default", 700, 400);

      char direction = System.Convert.ToChar(directions);
```

Any idea how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course, I know what this "_String must be exactly one character long_" means. For `directions`, I didn't set the length. But, after several tries, I found that any input that more than 1 value will get this error. Instead, only input with 1 value (alphanumeric) works fine.

Comment: Remember a char is a single character, while a string is 0 or more characters strung together.

Comment: You didn't set the length, sure. But you set a value of _specific_ length, no? I think that 1 try is enough to determine that the string "12" is length of 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this: Its always strongly recommended to catch FormatException and ArgumentNullException like this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tochar?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Convert_ToChar_System_String_

```
char direction;

string directions = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("1 = Buy, 2 = Sell", "Select side", "Default", 700, 400);

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(directions) && directions.Trim().Length == 1)
  direction = System.Convert.ToChar(directions);
else {
  direction = directions.FirstOrDefault(); // if thats what your logic
}
```

or you can use:

```
char direction = directions.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: It works, thanks! But why can't I use `System.Convert.ToChar();` to convert in my case?

Comment: is your string length 1 or you are putting space in your input or pressing an enter.. etc..so many reasons..

Comment: you may also want to check for null like this: `directions?.FirstOrDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

Why did you put "Default" as default response? You either leave it blank, or put "1" or "2" there.

Also check for user's answer before converting to direction :

```
If directions <> "1" And directions <> "2" Then
    'display error message to user
Else
    char direction = System.Convert.ToChar(directions);
    'proceed with your business logic
End If
```